# Identify PII dataset in text file and encrypt it which could be decrypted later?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, pii

I have a chat text file which consists of PII dataset such as Name, identification number, phone no etc. I have to encrypt the PII information at source and decrypt it again at destination using Python 3.7. I used cryptography.fernet to convert but it is used to convert the entire file that too with a single key. What could be the possible solution?

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
key = b'aA1QRKHyk9lV8LM740tj_dcn045KkOSU7SM0hVPYfhQ=' #the key is random 
input_file = 'test.txt'
output_file = 'test.encrypted'

with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
data = f.read()

fernet = Fernet(key)
encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
f.write(encrypted)
```

The problem here is it encrypts whole file and decrypts whole file and with the same one key which I have hardcoded in the code which is not a correct way to do.

test file(unstructured) has content:

```
hello john with id no 345678 with phone no 12345678
hello peter with id no 87654 with phone no 45678990
```

I need to encrypt name, id no and phone no here. What could be the best possible solution here to encrypt PII data individually with the keys which could identify Names,id and phone no separately and later decrypted? A better library to use? A sample code would be helpful

Comment: It seems that you're using an empty key - `key = b''`.

Comment: I had given a value to key, key = b'aA1QRKHyk9lV8LM740tj_dcn045KkOSU7SM0hVPYfhQ=' something like this but then it just has single key for entire file, but the problem is its encrypting entire file and not just PII data and I have learnt that Fernet is not a good option for large files. How could I work just on PII encryption and decryption? My question is like is there a better way for this problem considering the input will be text unstructured file? even a sample code for the work around could help? will update the key in my question as well

Comment: You don't have to include your key, just remove this line `key = b''` because it can be confusing to readers. Fernet uses AES-256-CBC for encryption, and you should be able to encrypt large files with it, as long as they're small enough that you can store them in a string. If the file is larger then you can use the ciphers in `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers`, but it would be best to use Fernet, if you're not very experienced.

Comment: @t.m.adam But I have to again use the generated key during encryption to decrypt later at that point how should I track the key which was used during encryption? Also if you can let me know it I can hunt the specific PII data only in file and not the entire file?

Comment: Well, you'll have to safely store your key/s somewhere. You don't have to use a new key for each file, you could just use one key. I don't know how to parse a file for PII data, so I can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: That's an awfully badly structured text file. You can use fernet on each line, but you would need to *find the right records as well*. So possibly you should keep some identifier outside of the ciphertext (you could / should put it in the additional data to be protected for integrity though). So you would get a file like `ID : base64(ciphertext)` or something similar.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Even if i use fernet in each line how could I target specific PII data like Name or id in that? will be it ok to write regex for each pattern encountered. Is there any sample code which you can put in? or any other library for getting PII from unstructured data as the input will be unstructured only because it is will be raw chats between people